# A panel to change 3d object properties when right click on it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a UI system to edit selected 3D objects. I have spheres on the screen and I want to be able to edit their proprieties (radius for example). In order to do that I want the user to be able to click on a sphere and then it show a panel next to the object. When the user changes slider value the radius of the sphere which as been clicked on change. Using the new unity event system, I think it's easy to achieve, but I'm a new to unity and even if I know the basic I don't know how to organize this properly.

At the end my goal would be to select multiple sphere, right click and edit the radius to all selected spheres.!
Any tips on how to do that ? Sorry for my poor english. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

- Keep a `bool` for tracking if the object is selected, say, `bool _isSelected`
- Toggle this boolean in the [`OnMouseUpAsButton()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUpAsButton.html) function. This function is called when you click on an object and release that click on the same object. Unity's [`OnMouseXXX()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=onmouse) interfaces are very good for handling mouse events. You just need to define this function in the sphere objects' script.
- Put together a [`Slider`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) and arrange its value interval from editor. Define a function that will edit the scale value of the spheres and tie that function to that slider.

Below you can see an example of how I did that in a game of mine.

[image]

Unity simply catches the slider's value if you provide it with a `public void _f(float val)`. It will appear on the top of the list as "Dynamic float". So, in your case, your slider update function should look like this:

```
public void SphereScaleSliderUpdate(float val)
{
    foreach (GameObject sphere in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("your tag here"))
    {
        if (sphere.IsSelected) // don't forget to provide a public getter for _isSphere variable
        {
            sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(val, val, val);
        }
    }
}
```

- Also, you need to create another script for toggling the menu(Canvas/Panel<sub>(optional)</sub>) that contains the slider, and you may add it to another object, like a UIManager. Assign the `Canvas` in the game hierarchy to a variable in that script, and then scan for RClick in the `Update()` function of the UIManager.

.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)   // RClick event
    {
        // makes the slider appear through enabling canvas
        _canvasHandle.enabled = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, just realized, the shown function and the function assigned to slider value in the screenshot are not the same. Take it as this is just how you assign a function: the defined function needs to be `public void` and receive a parameter of type `float`. And then you choose it from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot quite clear, but it's only working for one particular sphere am I wrong? Now I need to make it work if multiple spheres are selected.

Comment: @AnotherNoobDev Have the other spheres got the same script as the sphere that you can change its scale?

Comment: Yes but the slider will only be linked to one sphere i think ... Cause i select a Sphere as target for the slider than i chose the SphereScaleSliderUpdate(float val) in the inspector.

Comment: Can you make sure you can successfully toggle the `bool _isSelected` of the spheres ? Try removing the `if(_isSelected)` condition to see whether you can change all the spheres' scale. If that works, this means you only selected one sphere. In that case, make the bool public and check the variable from the scene view for debugging purposes (to see whats going wrong).

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/UdmMXgt) Both of my sphere are selected I checked. My second sphere doesn't change radius cause only the first one is linked to the slider. The only solution is to link all spheresSphereScaleSliderUpdate (float Val) to the slider? In my project I generate a lot of spheres so it can be hard to do, I was trying to figure out how to edit only selected sphere with one function linked to the slider (maybe using a list). And again thanks a lot for your help. EDIT : it's working with each Shere SphereScaleSliderUpdate(float val) linked to the slider just not very handy

Comment: @AnotherNoobDev You have to read about [Prefabs](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html). Make a sphere prefab. Attach the sphere script to the prefab and then put sphere prefabs to the scene. This ensures all spheres are the same. Or just manually drag and drop the sphere script to every sphere in the scene, but to avoid that, we prefer prefabs:)

Comment: I know how to instantiate prefab. The issue is that I have to link each Sphere SphereScaleSliderUpdate (float Val) to the slider, in order to update all selected spheres. I can do that by adding a listener to the slider for each sphere, but I hoped there was a better way.

Comment: aaah now I see what I missed. Ok. You better move the OnValueChange function to the UI manager and then scan for sphere objects in the scene preferrably using tags. From all the sphere objects, you have to check their `IsSelected` and then change their scale using a loop. I'll update the answer shortly.